# How long do you keep the rattlesnake card in Bang!

Tags: bang

I just bought the Valley of Shadows extension for Emiliano Sciarra's game Bang!
I can't find anywhere in the rules (or the internet) if you're supposed to discard the card after being bitten by the snake.
Does it work like the Dynamite or like the Jail card? Do you keeep it until you can self "cat balou" it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It stays in play and checks every turn until someone (most likely yourself) either Cat Balou's or Panic's it away.

**Edit:**

[This thread on Boardgame geek has the same answer.](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1524816/rattlesnake-does-it-ever-move-or-go-away)